# Is a photon really a moving object or is it caused by momentum exchange between parts of a immense 3D Newton cradle?

Tags: energy, momentum, space

I was interested in watching how dominos fall as part of a hugh series of them arranged that the effect can be transferred. Very simmilar is the Newton cradle where objects that are strictly localised can transfer momentum. Can a photon be something not quite identical but simmilar?Is it likely to think so if we know that vibration can not be at rest and it also has no change in velocity which is the statistical description of a photon?

Comment: Vibrations _can_ be at rest, though (that's what standing waves are), and they _can_ change velocity when they move from one medium to another.

Comment: @probably_someone A standing wave is a combination of two waves in opposite direction which both have same velocity in vacuum.. Different speed in a different media... Yes if you put some mass to an element of the cradle I think it is more inert and its velocity needed to let the vibration further is smaller so the vibration could go on but with smaller velocity.... so I think this possibility is not something to just through away....

Answer (score 1):

The [Michelson Morley experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment) showed definitively that there is no luminiferous  aether, that the energy of light is propelled through vacuum, no medium needed. Photons are found experimentally to be the underlying structure of classical electromagnetism.[This single photon experiment](https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/) shows the effect of photons scattering on a double slit and the build up to the classical effect.

There is nothing for photons to impinge on and create a Newton's cradle effect .

Comment: Is the space really a nothing? How then explain Hubble flow... how all that massive gallaxies are dragged along with space expansion? There must be something where there is no visible matter....

Comment: Einstein's equation models   space curvature  (i.e. observed gravity at newtonian level) with  the energy-momentum tensor . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations . general relativity is the  mainstream physics model

Comment: if there is no energy momentum tensor , space is flat.

Comment: Really nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

In 4-space, the "distance" a photon travels is zero, even if it is emitted on Alpha Centauri and detected here on Earth.  The Newton's Cradle analogy isn't too outlandish if all the balls between the front and the back are eliminated, the front ball is the emitter and the back ball is the detector. The positions and times of the emission and detection events are different, but the 4- space "distance" between them is zero.  Turning that into a useful theory of electromagnetism might be difficult though!